# How to upload files to one drive from .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I need to maintain a historical record of certain documents, my initial solution was to copy them to a shared folder from .NET, but that doesn't seem so safe to me. Can I make the upload of those files to One Drive by using .NET with C#? If so, I would like documentation about it, I've already done a free search and I haven't found anything that could satisfy my needs. I apologize if the question is way too vague. Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this can help you out:

Using the code:

```
public string OneDriveApiRoot { get; set; } = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/";
```

Upload file to OneDrive

```
//this is main method of upload file to OneDrive 
public async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(string filePath, string oneDrivePath) 
{ 
    //get the upload session,we can use this session to upload file resume from break point 
    string uploadUri = await GetUploadSession(oneDrivePath); 

    //when file upload is not finish, the result is upload progress, 
    //When file upload is finish, the result is the file information. 
    string result = string.Empty; 
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath)) 
    { 
        long position = 0; 
        long totalLength = stream.Length; 
        int length = 10 * 1024 * 1024; 

        //In one time, we just upload a part of file 
        //When all file part is uploaded, break out in this loop 
        while (true) 
        { 
        //Read a file part 
        byte[] bytes = await ReadFileFragmentAsync(stream, position, length); 

        //check if arrive file end, when yes, break out with this loop 
        if (position >= totalLength) 
        { 
            break; 
        } 

        //Upload the file part 
        result = await UploadFileFragmentAsync(bytes, uploadUri, position, totalLength); 

        position += bytes.Length; 
    } 
} 

return result; 
} 

private async Task<string> GetUploadSession(string oneDriveFilePath) 
{ 
    var uploadSession = await AuthRequestToStringAsync( 
    uri: $"{OneDriveApiRoot}drive/root:/{oneDriveFilePath}:/upload.createSession", 
    httpMethod: HTTPMethod.Post, 
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

JObject jo = JObject.Parse(uploadSession); 

return jo.SelectToken("uploadUrl").Value<string>(); 
} 

private async Task<string> UploadFileFragmentAsync(byte[] datas, string uploadUri, long position, long totalLength) 
{ 
    var request = await InitAuthRequest(uploadUri, HTTPMethod.Put, datas, null); 
    request.Request.Headers.Add("Content-Range", $"bytes {position}-{position + datas.Length - 1}/{totalLength}"); 

return await request.GetResponseStringAsync(); 
}
```

Get Share Link: ( Javascript )

```
//This method use to get ShareLink, you can use the link in web or client terminal 
public async Task<string> GetShareLinkAsync(string fileID, OneDriveShareLinkType type, OneDrevShareScopeType scope) 
{ 
string param = "{type:'" + type + "',scope:'" + scope + "'}"; 

string result = await AuthRequestToStringAsync( 
    uri: $"{OneDriveApiRoot}drive/items/{fileID}/action.createLink", 
    httpMethod: HTTPMethod.Post, 
    data: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param), 
    contentType: "application/json"); 

return JObject.Parse(result).SelectToken("link.webUrl").Value<string>(); 
}
```

From: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-upload-file-to-21125137

Comment: <333 i was reading a microsoft project to see documents ,and ia was frustrated

Comment: I understand, but anyway give it a try!

Comment: @JustFair any chance you had a new link for the code reference?

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution for beginners:

- Install OneDrive app on your computer then login to your account and set a folder to it.
- Then you just need to copy your files in the folder you set in the last step. It would be synced automatically by OneDrive application.

```
File.Copy(sourceFileFullPath,OneDriveFileFullPath);
```